# How to achieve half tone effect

Tags: shadows, halftone

I'd like to use this sort of a half tone effect on shadows shown in this image. How is this achieved?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a pattern brush

Comment: Creating a halftone pattern from e.g. some grey noise should be possible in most reasonably sophisticated image editors. In fact, [searching this site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=create+halftone+pattern) should return some useful hints.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop has a built in halftone filter (Filter>Other>Color halftone) that can create this effect.

[image: halftone effect in photoshop]

Answer (score 1):

In Photoshop...

Duplicate your layer via copy.

Convert the new file (the copy) to **grayscale**, than to **bitmap**. Leave the resolution untouched.

Aplly a halftone as your desire.

Convert it back to **grayscale**, than to **RGB**.

Drag that layer back to the original illustration.

See the image bellow.

[image]

Comment: Note that this method works with any software that can convert to bitmap (imagemagick, GIMP etc) as it does not rely on filters

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it was created with a brush preset or pattern brush.

I would download any preset you find that you like and then just play around with the opacity settings.

It is comprised of several layers at <50% opacity.

This is just a quick example of how to achieve it.

[image]

If you want to do this is Illustrator you can find a lot of pre-made vector patterns or brushes. Then you again would just play around with the opacity to achieve the desired effect.